# highcharts,highstock,symbol is undefiend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm able to have some output with highstocks timeline chart, but when I hover on the chart, for every inch that my cursor moves, I get a javascript error:**symbol is undefiend**,

[is is the url to image from my error](http://tinybyte.persiangig.com/image/Errors/highcharts/Untitled.png)

this is my markup:

```
<div style="padding: 10px">
    <style>
        .highcharts-container {
            direction: ltr;
        }
    </style>


    <div id="widget47"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        'chart': {
            'renderTo': 'widget47'
        },
        'exporting': {
            'enabled': true
        },
        'title': {
            'text': 'sale report in time period'
        },
        'yAxis': {
            'plotLines': [{
                'value': 1,
                'width': 2,
                'color': 'silver'
            }]
        },
        'credits': {
            'enabled': false
        },
        'rangeSelector': {
            'selected': 4
        },
        'plotOptions': {
            'series': {
                'compare': 'value'
            }
        },
        'series': [{
            'name': 'M1POS',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 47, 45), 2100000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 0,
            '_symbolIndex': 0,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'Cipherlab PDA CP50',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 47, 45), 2100000.],
                [Date.UTC(2013, 11, 03, 11, 07, 19), 6300000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 1,
            '_symbolIndex': 1,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'Cipherlab PDA CP 60',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 47, 45), 2100000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 2,
            '_symbolIndex': 2,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'Cipherlab PDA CP30',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 47, 45), 4200000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 3,
            '_symbolIndex': 3,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA M3T(WiFi.Bluetooth)',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 47, 45), 4500000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 4,
            '_symbolIndex': 4,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA 6200(Wifi.Scanner.Bluthooth)',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 47, 45), 7700000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 5,
            '_symbolIndex': 5,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA 6500(Gsm.Wifi.Scaner.Camera.Bluthooth.Gps)',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 48, 02), 1800000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 6,
            '_symbolIndex': 6,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA B8000',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 48, 39), 1700000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 7,
            '_symbolIndex': 7,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA MM3(WiFi.Scanner.Bluetooth)',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 48, 39), 1800000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 8,
            '_symbolIndex': 8,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA Orange stylus pen',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 51, 08), 3500000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 9,
            '_symbolIndex': 9,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA Orange(GSM.Wifi.Scaner.Camera.Bluthooth.GPS.RFID)',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 51, 44), 500000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 10,
            '_symbolIndex': 10,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA M3T (WiFi Scaner Bluetooth)',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 51, 44), 500000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 11,
            '_symbolIndex': 11,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA Sky(GSM.Wifi.Scaner.Camera.Bluthooth.GPS.RFID)',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 53, 02), 1100000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 12,
            '_symbolIndex': 12,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA Sky(Gsm.Wifi.Scaner.Camera.Bluthooth.Gps)',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 53, 02), 1100000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 13,
            '_symbolIndex': 13,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'M3 PDA Sky(Wifi.Bluthooth)',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2013, 09, 11, 10, 53, 02), 1100000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 14,
            '_symbolIndex': 14,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'Pars  تبلت صنعتی پی دی ای صنعتی',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 15, 08, 35, 03), 90000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 29, 10, 30, 12), 14000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 19), 20000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 19, 09, 15, 34), 30000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 20, 10, 37, 38), 0.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 22, 12, 07, 59), 0.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 15,
            '_symbolIndex': 15,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'LCD 9',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 15, 08, 35, 03), 187300.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 19, 09, 15, 34), 30000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 20, 10, 38, 14), 0.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 22, 12, 08, 31), 0.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 16,
            '_symbolIndex': 16,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'Test Pack',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 15, 11, 10, 52), 192000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 17,
            '_symbolIndex': 17,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'dsssffsdf',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 15, 11, 11, 14), 96000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 18,
            '_symbolIndex': 18,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'LCD 10',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 15, 11, 14, 32), 52500.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 29, 10, 30, 12), 14000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 01, 09, 14, 53), 24500.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 19), 30000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 20, 10, 37, 38), 0.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 22, 12, 07, 59), 0.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 19,
            '_symbolIndex': 19,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'LCD 6',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 15, 11, 27, 33), 7500.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 29, 10, 30, 12), 14000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 20, 10, 38, 47), 0.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 22, 12, 07, 59), 0.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 20,
            '_symbolIndex': 20,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'LCD 7',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 15, 11, 28, 25), 1300.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 49), 10000.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 20, 10, 38, 14), 0.],
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 22, 12, 07, 59), 0.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 21,
            '_symbolIndex': 21,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'Woosim Mobile Printer PortiW40',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 01, 29, 10, 30, 12), 14000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 22,
            '_symbolIndex': 22,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }, {
            'name': 'Woosim Mobile Printer WSP-i250',
            'data': [
                [Date.UTC(2014, 02, 18, 09, 16, 19), 20000.]
            ],
            '_colorIndex': 23,
            '_symbolIndex': 23,
            'marker': {
                'enabled': true
            }
        }]
    });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

as you can see my data is ordered by date in ascending format, but I get error #15??

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The undefined symbol error appears when you specify a value of 5 or above for _symbolIndex. I'm not sure what your _symbolIndex settings are meant to be doing, they're not part of the API docs, but if you take them out, the problem goes away.

The error 15 is being caused by a misordered date. The Date.UTC function (confusingly) expects a zero-based month parameter but you're giving it one-based months, so where you've got:

```
Date.UTC(2014, 01, 29, 10, 30, 12)
```

you haven't set January 29th as you might expect, you've set February 29th (in a non leap year) which JavaScript interprets as March 1st.